# Cannot access my localhost and phpmyadmin

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I have my website running locally on my XAMPP but when loading into localhost I'm getting the options to select a certain folder to open then I get the message: "Error establishing a database connection" and when I click on Admin in XAMPP I get the 403 Forbidden error that says "You don't have permission to access this resource."

I have tried to revert my commits on GitFork to see if that would fix the issue but to no success, moreover, I have reinstalled XAMPP and re-clone my repo and unfortunately still have the same issue.

In addition, I have repaired my table in phpmyadmin (didn't fix the "Error establishing a database connection") when I did have the permission to access it but now cannot even do that.